# Integration with google-plus crashing

Tags: ios, google-plus

I am trying to use Google-plus iOS SDK in my application. I went through the steps as mentione [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started) but while trying to sign in when i am calling below method to get an instance:

```
[GPPSignIn sharedInstance]
```

it is crashing with message:

`-[__NSCFString gtm_stringByUnescapingFromURLArgument]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb1c8800`

Any idea what i might be doing wrong?

Comment: I think you're going to need edit your question and paste in additional code and also additional logging if it is available.

Comment: yes, you are right, but that is the first line of code in which I tried to get instance. Apart from that only integration steps I executed.

Comment: Have you added all required frameworks and imported the ones from the Google+ SDK ?

Comment: have you tried adding -ObjC to other linker flags